# Работа с PDF в JEE

Tags: java, postgresql, java-ee

Делаю на JSF страничку на которой будет каталог файлов PDF с возможностью удаления/добавления. Подскажите как лучше реализовать хранение PDF, сначала думал в базе данных хранить, но тогда возникнут трудности с иcпользованием JPA. В общем, объясните как это обычно делается.

Comment: Хранить так же, как любые другие файлы - в базе хранить сущности описывающие файл и путь до него на диске, а сам файл по указанному пути.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Понял, спасибо